# Is Spire.XLS C# support HDR - option when Excel file has no header file?

Tags: spire.xls

Is Spire.XLS C# support HDR - option when Excel file has no header file ? I have Excel file without header file. This is resolved in OLEDB driver in connection string HDR="No" Option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ExportDataTable(CellRange range, **bool exportColumnNames**)](https://www.e-iceblue.com/apireference/net/Spire.XLS/html/M_Spire_Xls_Worksheet_ExportDataTable_1.htm) method of Spire.Xls.Worksheet class to read worksheet data into a data table and determine whether to export the first row in the worksheet range as header row in the data table.

Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.LoadFromFile("Input.xlsx");
    Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
    DataTable dt = sheet.ExportDataTable(sheet.Range, false);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

[image]